# javascript loop over ruby database object

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I am trying to go over all builds objects in project (has_many relation) and set yy to be the last updated_at one with status 'completed'

The following javascript command which reside in my haml file:

```
var yy = #{project.builds.select{|b| b.status == 'completed'}.last.try(:updated_at)};
```

throw `" Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number"` (although, I see in debug mode that it managed to get the correct value)

what is the correct way to go over my builds from javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need quotes here:

```
var yy = "#{ project.builds.select{|b| b.status == 'completed'}.last.try(:updated_at) }";
```